# How to draw stair case diagram using tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

the following is the diagram I want to draw

[image]

Comment: could you please provide a minimal working example of what you've got so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dotted pattern is not really the best, but this might be a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& & & & \bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[r,"\xi"] & E_1 \arrow[d,"\eta"] \\
& & & \bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & E_2 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & \bullet \\
& & {} \arrow[r] & E_3 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] \arrow[lldd,-,loosely dotted]& \bullet \\
& {} \arrow[d] & & {}\\
\bullet \arrow[d,"\mu",swap] \arrow[r] & E_n \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & {} \\
\bullet \arrow[r,"\lambda",swap] & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]